# Missing value for RR-interval (BLE / Polar device)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I'm owning a Polar H10 device and I'm interested in the heart rate as well as RR-interval which I read out with the official bluetooth low energy API of Android. The Polar device sends every every second a package with the heart rate and the RR-interval. Now I have recognized that in every such package is a heart rate value but in some packages there are no RR-interval values (The value of the RR-interval is -1).

Why does this happen? Is my device broken or did I made a mistake in the implementation or does somebody else also face this issue?

Edit: Here is the code. In the method `public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)` I'm receiving changed values from the Polar Device. This method is triggered approximately every second. Then I parse the characteristic as follows:

```
    public int[] parse(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

        double heartRate = extractHeartRate(c);
        Integer[] interval = extractBeatToBeatInterval(c);

        int[] result = null;
        if (interval != null) {
            result = new int[interval.length + 1];
        } else {
            result = new int[2];
            result[1] = -1;
        }
        result[0] = (int) heartRate;

        if (interval != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < interval.length; i++) {
                result[i+1] = interval[i];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }


private static double extractHeartRate(
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

    int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
    Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate flag: " + flag);
    int format = -1;
    // Heart rate bit number format
    if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
        format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
        Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
    } else {
        format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
        Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
    }

    final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received heart rate: %d", heartRate));
    return heartRate;
}

private static Integer[] extractBeatToBeatInterval(
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

    int flag = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
    int format = -1;
    int energy = -1;
    int offset = 1; // This depends on hear rate value format and if there is energy data
    int rr_count = 0;

    if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
        format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
        Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
        offset = 3;
    } else {
        format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
        Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
        offset = 2;
    }
    if ((flag & 0x08) != 0) {
        // calories present
        energy = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16, offset);
        offset += 2;
        Log.d(TAG, "Received energy: {}"+ energy);
    }
    if ((flag & 0x16) != 0){
        // RR stuff.
        Log.d(TAG, "RR stuff found at offset: "+ offset);
        Log.d(TAG, "RR length: "+ (characteristic.getValue()).length);
        rr_count = ((characteristic.getValue()).length - offset) / 2;
        Log.d(TAG, "RR length: "+ (characteristic.getValue()).length);
        Log.d(TAG, "rr_count: "+ rr_count);
        if (rr_count > 0) {
            Integer[] mRr_values = new Integer[rr_count];
            for (int i = 0; i < rr_count; i++) {
                mRr_values[i] = characteristic.getIntValue(
                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16, offset);
                offset += 2;
                Log.d(TAG, "Received RR: " + mRr_values[i]);
            }
            return mRr_values;
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "No RR data on this update: ");
    return null;
}
```

The first element returned by the parse method is the heart rate and the second element is the RR-interval. It happens that sometimes the second element is -1 (i.e. no RR-interval detected).

Comment: Show us the code

Comment: @pablisco I have added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your Polar device or the software you posted.

The RR-interval measure may be missing from some transmitted packets and the `if ((flag & 0x16) != 0)` accounts for this case.

Suppose for example that your device send a heart measure every second and you have 50 beats/sec: there will be some intervals where the RR interval is not measured because there isnt a detected beat in that second (it is a simplified explanation, just to get the point).